# Camera app showing a blank scree in odin

Tags: release-odin, camera

[image]

But in my teams application I am able see my video footage

Comment: Same issue here. No image in the Camera app, but Zoom and Webcamoid are able to access the video feed without issue. 2015 MacBook Pro 13" integrated webcam.

Comment: it works after selecting the option in the camera dropdown .